# How to force an image to be centered?

Tags: graphics, formatting

I cannot make an image to be centered no matter what I do. I have searched through similar questions but did not find any useful answers for this case.

I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bitis.png) when compiling even though the image [itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SauqZ.jpg) is perfectly centered.

This is the command I use (I am using a template file)

```
\stranka{}%
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.45]
{./pictures/zadani.jpg}}\sffamily\Huge\centering\ 
    {\sffamily\centering }
```

I am  using TeXmaker.

Comment: Why do you employ `scale=0.45` instead of `width=\linewidth`? Incidentally, what does `\stranka` do? And what's the purpose of `\sffamily\Huge\centering\ ` and of `{\sffamily\centering }`?

Comment: I am new to LateX and I have been using this template that worked for everyone else. I did not see a reason to change anything. If I use width=\linewidth as you suggest, it is centered (YAY), but it is too small. is there a way to make the image larger without using scale?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "too small". So far, you've provided no information whatsoever about the page size or the widths of the margins. Without this information, it's well-nigh impossible to give actionable and useful advice on what you should do.

Comment: `\newcommand{\stranka}[3]{
   \newpage
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \noindent%
 \makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}%
  
  \parbox[c][0pt][c]{\textwidth}{#2}%
   
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}%
 }%
 \parbox[c][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}{%
  \parbox[t][][t]{\textwidth}{#1}%
  
  \vspace{\stretch{1}}
    
  \parbox[b][][b]{\textwidth}{#3}%
 }
  \newpage

  \if@twoside
     \thispagestyle{empty}
     \cleardoublepage
  \fi
}`

Comment: this is what "stranka" does. sorry about the formatting

Comment: @JanPisl: Either use `\centering \includegraphics[.]{..}`, or `\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[.]{..}}`.

Comment: @JanPisl Please, add the code to your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 2):

By all means, do get rid of the `\stranka` "wrapper" and use the following code instead:

```
\begin{figure}[p!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=\textheight,
                 keepaspectratio]{./pictures/zadani.jpg}
\end{figure}
```

Encasing the graphic in a `figure` environment and using the `p` placement specifier ensures that it'll be placed on a page by itself. (Incidentally, absent further information, I can see no good reason for running `\thispagestyle{empty}`.)

Comment: when I use the code you provided, it is centered, however, two other issues arise - first, it does not occupy the entire page (that is what I meant when I said it is too small). and also, it appears on a different page than it was before (even though I put your command at the same place as was the one before). and i am afraid i need the pages to be in a specific order

Comment: as for your comment where you say "you've provided no information whatsoever about the page size or the widths of the margins" - where do I get this information?

Comment: @JanPisl - Do you have any commands such as `\textwidth` and `\textheight` in your preamble, do you you load the `geometry` package and set the margin widths directly? Do consider posting the preamble of your document in the  body of your query.

Comment: @JanPisl - Do you maybe have pending, not-yet-typeset `figure` environments in your document? If you must generate an immediate page break, simply insert the instruction `\clearpage` immediately before `\begin{figure}[p!]`.

Answer (score 2):

To centre an image that is larger than the textwidth, write

```
\centerline{\includegraphics...{...}}
```

Comment: I dont know what you mean. If I use "\makebox[\200pt]{\includegraphics{./pictures/zadani.jpg}}" (as far as I understand that is what you suggest;  200pt is just a random value), I get an error:  ! Undefined control sequence.<argument> (...)

Comment: Try again with the above. @egreg edited my answer, but I didn't like his edit so I rolled it back :) He would have you write `\noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{...}}` instead of `\centerline{...}`.